# How to restrict the background color of a TGroupBox to the area INSIDE of the border frame of the box?

Tags: delphi, groupbox, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 win-32 VCL Application in Windows 10, for a `TGroupBox` I have set:

```
GroupBox1.Color := clSkyBlue;
```

As you can see from this screenshot, this color expands to the area OUTSIDE of the border frame (and also includes the frame itself):

[image]

I have looked in the IDE Object Inspector for `TGroupBox`, but have not found any property which allows this restriction of the background color to the area INSIDE the border frame.

The only way to make this restriction is to have an empty caption:

[image]

But I need a caption for the GroupBox.

How can I restrict the background color of the box to the area INSIDE the border frame of the box while keeping the caption of the box? Is there a trick to force the `TGroupBox` to an optimized drawing of the background? (Maybe by drawing the caption OVER or ABOVE the border frame?)

Comment: It is easy to fill the effective client rectangle of the group box with a colour, but that will not look pretty (IMHO), because that will leave the old background colour for a few pixels at the top, below the upper border. But probably the best approach is to create your own group box control.

Comment: Would it be possible to draw the `TGroupBox` caption OUTSIDE (ABOVE) the border frame?

Comment: Anything is possible if you replace the drawing code with your own code. This amounts to creating your own control, which is easy.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @user1580348 What about simply using a `TPanel` with a `TLabel` above it at the desired offset?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right.